# Using \only<#> to change text color causes spacing issues

Tags: beamer, spacing, color

Hello and thank you in advance for your help!

I'm comparing the following two commands:

1. `This is a \only<1>{test}\only<2>{\textcolor{red}{test}}.`
2. `$\only<1>{\max_{(x,y)}}\only<2>{\textcolor{red}{\max_{(x,y)}}}$`

The first one works fine, and makes the text turn red.

The second one also makes the text turn red. However, it causes a small shift in the spacing. I can't figure out what is causing this shift, has anyone else run into this problem before?

Is it problems with the math environment?

Comment: I suspect that `$\only<1>{...}$` leaves some empty box at the start of the math formula, so `\max` is slightly displaced because it's a math operator following an (empty) ordinary symbol. The same doesn't happen with `\max` inside `\textcolor`, because this starts another level of grouping and `\max` is the first item in the subformula.

Comment: What about \alert<2>{$\max_{(x,y)}$}?

Answer (score 8):

Please always post complete documents not just fragments.

The whatsit nodes needed for `\only` cause math atoms in math mode that can affect the spacing. Easiest is to put an empty math atom `{}` before the `\max` in both cases.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

    This is a \only<1>{test}\only<2>{\textcolor{red}{test}}.

    $\only<1>{{}\max_{(x,y)}}\only<2>{\textcolor{red}{{}\max_{(x,y)}}}$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use math mode for each expression separately (this seems (at least to me) more syntactically correct):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

This is a \only<1>{test}\only<2>{\textcolor{red}{test}}.

\only<1>{$\max_{(x,y)}$}\only<2>{\textcolor{red}{$\max_{(x,y)}$}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```