# Underbrace color change using \only<> and \textcolor{}{} slightly shifts the content

Tags: beamer, color, overlays

I am making a presentation using `beamer` and am trying to make `underbrace{}{}` appear using `\textcolor{}{}` and `\only<>`. I use the code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}

% Just some newcommands.
\newcommand{\msum}[2][]{\sum \limits_{#2}^{#1}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left|\left|{#1}\right|\right|}
\newcommand{\nqb}[1]{{#1}^{\perp}}
\newcommand{\nqj}[1]{\check{#1}}
\newcommand{\textblack}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textb}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textg}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textr}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textw}[1]{\textcolor{white}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>
        {
            \[
                \nqj{\psi}_j:=\textw{\underbrace{\textblack{\psi_j}}_{\bm{g}}
                \textblack{-}
                \underbrace{\textblack{\msum[j-1]{k=1}(\psi_j,\nqb{\psi}_k)\nqb{\psi}_k}}_{\bm{h}}},
                \quad\nqb{\psi}_j:=\dfrac{\nqj{\psi}_j}{\norm{\nqj{\psi}_j}}
            \]
        }
        \only<2->
        {
            \[
                \nqj{\psi}_j:=\textblack{\underbrace{\textblack{\psi_j}}_{\bm{g}}
                \textblack{-}
                \underbrace{\textblack{\msum[j-1]{k=1}(\psi_j,\nqb{\psi}_k)\nqb{\psi}_k}}_{\bm{h}}},
                \quad\nqb{\psi}_j:=\dfrac{\nqj{\psi}_j}{\norm{\nqj{\psi}_j}}
            \]
        }       
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

in which I only change the color of a part of the text. Nonetheless, looking at the two resulting slides, the content shifts a bit. How can I avoid this? Or is there perhaps a better way to get `\underbrace`s to appear?

The solution as proposed in [Using \only<#> to change text color causes spacing issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116946/using-only-to-change-text-color-causes-spacing-issues) does not work, I believe.

Comment: Do you want `white` text, or invisible text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the matter of color. With the same color a vertical shift is also visible. But now `\vfill` stabilizes the equation. (Without the picture, but one can easily verify).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}

% Just some newcommands.
\newcommand{\msum}[2][]{\sum \limits_{#2}^{#1}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left|\left|{#1}\right|\right|}
\newcommand{\nqb}[1]{{#1}^{\perp}}
\newcommand{\nqj}[1]{\check{#1}}
\newcommand{\textblack}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textb}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textg}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textr}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textw}[1]{\textcolor{white}{#1}}



\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>
        {
            \[
                \nqj{\psi}_j:=\textw{\underbrace{\textblack{\psi_j}}_{\bm{g}}
                \textblack{-}
                \underbrace{\textblack{\msum[j-1]{k=1}(\psi_j,\nqb{\psi}_k)\nqb{\psi}_k}}_{\bm{h}}},
                \quad\nqb{\psi}_j:=\dfrac{\nqj{\psi}_j}{\norm{\nqj{\psi}_j}}
            \]
      \vfill  }
        \only<2->
        {
            \[
                \nqj{\psi}_j:=\textblack{\underbrace{\textblack{\psi_j}}_{\bm{g}}
                \textblack{-}
                \underbrace{\textblack{\msum[j-1]{k=1}(\psi_j,\nqb{\psi}_k)\nqb{\psi}_k}}_{\bm{h}}},
                \quad\nqb{\psi}_j:=\dfrac{\nqj{\psi}_j}{\norm{\nqj{\psi}_j}}
            \]
    \vfill    }       

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\color` instead of `\textcolor`. The main advantage is that `\color` is overlay-aware, which means you can obtain the same result without repeating your text: you can use `{\color<1>{white} text...}` to have the text colored in white only on first overlay.

And as a nice side-effect (probably some magic), the content no longer moves between overlays.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}

% Just some newcommands.
\newcommand{\msum}[2][]{\sum \limits_{#2}^{#1}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left|\left|{#1}\right|\right|}
\newcommand{\nqb}[1]{{#1}^{\perp}}
\newcommand{\nqj}[1]{\check{#1}}
\newcommand{\textblack}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textb}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textg}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textr}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textw}[1]{\textcolor{white}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \[
    \nqj{\psi}_j:={\color<1>{white}\color<2>{black}\underbrace{\textblack{\psi_j}}_{\bm{g}}
      \textblack{-}
      \underbrace{\textblack{\msum[j-1]{k=1}(\psi_j,\nqb{\psi}_k)\nqb{\psi}_k}}_{\bm{h}}},
    \quad\nqb{\psi}_j:=\dfrac{\nqj{\psi}_j}{\norm{\nqj{\psi}_j}}
    \]

\end{frame}
```